# which approach is better to manipulate database in android

Tags: android, listview, android-contentprovider, android-loadermanager

In my android app i am performing sql data extensively where i need to download the data from server , store it into database and populating it on the `ListView`.

moreover, i need to perform the database search and filter the data in a `ListView` too.

so far in my past projects i have used simple method to manipulate database like manually opening & closing database , getting data from database using cursor and storing it in a array list and populating over `ListView`.

after exploring i came across the `ContentResolver` and `LoaderManager` and tried few samples too but i am not able to decide what to use where i need to perform more database operation with search in a `ListView`.

I would even love to know in which scenario what approach is preferable.

i am waiting for `commonsware` comments too ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ContentResolver/ContentProvider is meant for providing data to other applications.  If you aren't going to do that, then using it is clunky and overkill.  It really doesn't provide any value, and even Google's own docs suggest not using it for inside of your app.

LoaderManager-  meh.  The idea of a Loader is useful, and you're probably already using it-  a loader is just the idea of reading large amounts of data from your DB on an AsyncTask.  LoaderManager will provide some efficiency gains if you're being restarted due to configuration changes, but there's other ways to achieve them.  It isn't a bad thing to use, but it will save you minimal to no work-  you still have to write a custom CursorLoader to make your db call, and you'll have some code to manage the loader manager.  You aren't wrong to use it, I'm just not convinced of its value.

Comment: if i use `LoaderManager` i got to use `ContentProvider` to access my database rite and you said there is another way to achieve , can please share what is way ?

Comment: No, Loaders and ContentProviders are separate.  If you use LoaderManager you must use a Loader, probably a CursorLoader.

Comment: you are rite we got to override `loadInBackground` of `CursorLoader` , but can you tell me what are the other efficient ways to manipulate , as when i have used the traditional way as i explained in my question , the issue i faced is when i am loading data in listview there is a little delay in population data over listview.